# react-draggable save position of element after re-render

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the [react-draggable library](https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-draggable) to allow elements to be dragged. After each re-render elements go back to their starting position. How can can I persist position of each mapped element.

```
  const handleStop = (event, dragElement) => {

    console.log(dragElement)
     
  };

//Console.log(dragElement)
{node: div.resizablebox.react-draggable.react-draggable-dragging.react-draggable-dragged, x: 670, y: -423, deltaX: 0, deltaY: 0, …}


   { numberofLines.map( (si, k) => (
       
        <>
  
        <Draggable 
        onStop={handleStop}
        > 
       <div>
        <CreateLine type={si.type} title={si.title} seriestitle={si.seriestitle} />
        </div>
        </Draggable>
        
       </>
      )

      )}
```